# A Galois extension of two roots.

Tags: galois-theory

Let $x$ be one of the nontrivial cubic roots of the unity and let $y$ be the cubic root of $2$.

Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$ is a Galois extension and then, show that is isomorphic to one of the groups of order $6$ by giving explicit isomorphisms.

I already know that the degree of the extension is $6$, so i don´t know if its isomorphic to $S_3$ or, $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3$, and obviously I don´t know how to make the correspondence.

Aditional, how I can prove that is a Galois extension?

Comment: What is your definition of a Galois extension?

Comment: I have four equivalences.   Let E/F be a finite Galois extension with Gal(E/F) its Galois Group.                       1.- E is the splitting field of some f(x) in F(X) that is separable.                                                    2.- #Gal (E/F) = (E:F)

Comment: 3.- E^Gal(E/F)=F           4.- Every p(x)in F(x) irreducible with a root in E have all its roots in E and its separable.   All of the four is esquivalent (and definition) of Galois extension.

Answer (score 1):

**Possible sketch:** Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)$ is the splitting field of $x^3-2 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Show that the Galois group is of order six. Show that there are automorphisms $\sigma : \omega \mapsto \omega^2$ and $\tau : \sqrt[3]{2} \mapsto \sqrt[3]{2}\omega$. The first is order $2$ and the second is order $3$ and hence together must generate the group. Check if these commute, and decide correspondingly whether the group is $\mathfrak{S}_3$ or $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/3$.